# Reading lines from a file based on a list of line numbers and writing output to a utility

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, pipe

I have a file with a list of lines I want to read from another file. I want to output those lines to a utility (`grep`) that lets me read the entire line and pull information from it. The file with the lines looks like this:

```
cat input.txt
2088
2089
2095
2096
```

For some reason I am stuck on this. I know `sed` can take a specific line number as an argument, but I can't figure how to get this into a variable to feed to it.

Comment: You have one file containing lines, and another file containing line numbers, and you want to produce a third file containing only the lines of the first file with the line numbers of the second file. - Did I understand your question correctly?

Answer (score 5):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{linesToPrint[$0];next}
     FNR in linesToPrint' line-numbers.txt file.txt
```

Comment: Doesn't work for repeated line numbers

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly something like this should work:

```
for i in $(cat numbers.txt); do cat lines.txt|tail -n +$i|head -n 1; done
```

For each of the numbers in file "numbers.txt" it extracts the corresponding line of the other file and prints it.

The same thing with `sed` and `xargs` looks like this:

```
xargs -i sed "{}q;d" lines.txt <numbers.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming [michas' interpretation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146218/reading-a-list-of-lines-from-a-file-writing-output-to-a-utility#comment236301_146218) is correct, here's an `awk` solution:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[i++]=$0} # Process the first file
     FNR!=NR{           # Process the second file
         for (i in a){
             if(FNR==a[i]){
                 print $0
             }
         }
     }' file_with_line_numbers other_file
```

In Perl:

```
perl -E '
    while(<>){
        chomp;
        if($file2) { say if exists $lines{$.} }
        else       { $lines{$_}++             }
    }   continue   { if (eof){$.=0; $file2++} }'\
    file_with_line_numbers other_file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/[^0-9]/d;s/.$/&p/' <input.txt |
sed -nf - file
```

That's two `sed`s working together. The first makes some small attempt at ensuring it only edits appropriate lines by refusing to print any line that contains a single non-numeric character and only editing any lines containing at least one character. Basically its job, though, is just to transform your list of line numbers into:

```
2088p
2089p
2095p
2096p
```

The second reads its command script from standard input and does not print lines by default, so all of those lines edited by `sed` the first become a list of commands for the `sed` the second. It performs these commands on `file`.

Apparently a similar technique has already been recommended, but there is a fundamental difference between a process's invocation arguments and input. There are distinct limits on argument lists like:

```
some_process $(seq a billion)
```

That kind of thing is bound to fail, but, as long as the process knows how to handle it, its input is theoretically unlimited. So, in this case, `sed` reads a file - the `|pipe` - as input and processes it like a `sed` script, which is far different than handing it a string of same length on its command line at invocation.

Answer (score 0):

Combine `sed` with [`xargs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) and [`printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html):

```
sed -n $(xargs printf "%sp;" < input.txt) data
```

[`-n` tells `sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) not to print lines unless you tell it to explicitly. [`xargs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) runs a command with the lines from standard input as its arguments. [`printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) will format each argument as described. The `$(...)` above expands to (for your sample file):

```
2088p;2089p;2095p;2096p;
```

which is a sequence of `sed` commands telling it to print lines 2088, 2089, 2095, and 2096.

In this way you read each file once, rather than many times for `xargs -i sed "{}q"` or piped `head` and `tail`.

Comment: This implodes if `printf`'s output exceeds the system's ARGMAX limit, but probably line length would break it long before then. Strike that - ARGLEN even before that, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Another `perl` solution:

```
$ perl -MList::Util=any -nle '
    BEGIN {
        open $fh, "<", "input.txt";
        @lines = <$fh>;
        close $fh;
    }
    print if any { $_ == $. } @lines;
' file
```