# Fast way to extract lines from a large file based on line numbers stored in another file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

I have a large file with 80 billion lines. Now I want to extract a few lines (around 10000) which I know the line number, what is the fastest way to deal with it.

Is it possible to extract those lines from using another file which contains the line numbers? The line numbers in the file of line numbers would not always be consecutive.

For example, the original file is:

```
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
...
```

the line number file:

```
1
3
4
```

the output:

```
0.1
0.3
0.4
```

Comment: If you expect to have to do this more than once, consider putting the lines into an SQL database or something of the sort.

Comment: Are they sequential 10000 lines or sporadic throughout the log file? If sequential and there's some unique pattern at the beginning you could just use grep -A 10000 <pattern> <filename>.

Comment: Thanks so much. I have added the information that these needed lines are not consecutive. And is it possible to extract those lines from using another file which contains the line numbers?

Comment: Does the file with the line numbers contain only the line numbers with each on a new line?

Comment: @NasirRiley Yes it contains the indices of the specific lines only, please have a look in my updated description. Thank you.

Comment: Are line numbers in line number file sorted?

Comment: @NateEldredge If it's a one-off thing, then the loading and indexing may take longer than the query.  Using a database would be preferred if you had to make many queries (not just the 10000).

Comment: Are the lines expected to be extracted in the order of the line numbers in the smaller file?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022384/bash-tool-to-get-nth-line-from-a-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading a list of lines from a file based on a list of line number writing output to a utility](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146218/reading-a-list-of-lines-from-a-file-based-on-a-list-of-line-number-writing-outpu)

Answer (score 5):

Here are an alternative method and a bit of benchmarking, adding to that [in Weijun Zhou's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/506236/315749).

#### `join`

Assuming you have a `data` file you want to extract rows from and a `line_numbers` file that lists the numbers of the rows you want to extract, if the sorting order of the output is not important you can use:

```bsh
join <(sort padded_line_numbers) <(nl -w 12 -n rz data) | cut -d ' ' -f 2-
```

This will number the lines of your `data` file, join it with the `padded_line_numbers` file on the first field (the default) and print out the common lines (excluding the join field itself, that is cut away).

`join` needs the input files to be sorted alphabetically. The aforementioned `padded_line_numbers` file has to be prepared by left-padding each line of your `line_numbers` file. E.g.:

```bsh
while read rownum; do
    printf '%.12d\n' "$rownum"
done <line_numbers >padded_line_numbers
```

The `-w 12 -n rz` options and arguments instruct `nl` to output 12 digits long numbers with leading zeros.

If the sorting order of the output has to match that of your `line_numbers` file, you can use:

```bsh
join -1 2 -2 1 <(nl padded_line_numbers | sort -k 2,2) \
    <(nl -w 12 -n rz data) |
    sort -k 2,2n |
    cut -d ' ' -f 3-
```

Where we are numbering the `padded_line_numbers` file, sorting the result alphabetically by its second field, joining it with the numbered `data` file and numerically sorting the result by the original sorting order of `padded_line_numbers`.

Process substitution is here used for convenience. If you can not or do not want to rely on it and, as it is likely, you are not willing to waste the storage needed for creating regular files to hold intermediate results, you can leverage named pipes:

```bsh
mkfifo padded_line_numbers
mkfifo numbered_data

while read rownum; do
    printf '%.12d\n' "$rownum"
done <line_numbers | nl | sort -k 2,2 >padded_line_numbers &

nl -w 12 -n rz data >numbered_data &

join -1 2 -2 1 padded_line_numbers numbered_data | sort -k 2,2n | cut -d ' ' -f 3-
```

#### Benchmarking

Since the peculiarity of your question is the number of rows in your `data` file, I thought it could be useful to test alternative approaches with a comparable amount of data.

For my tests I used a 3.2 billion lines data file. Each line is just 2 bytes of garbage coming from `openssl enc`, hex-encoded using `od -An -tx1 -w2` and with spaces removed with `tr -d ' '`:

```
$ head -n 3 data
c15d
061d
5787

$ wc -l data
3221254963 data
```

The `line_numbers` file has been created by randomly choosing 10,000 numbers between 1 and 3,221,254,963, without repetitions, using `shuf` from GNU Coreutils:

```bsh
shuf -i 1-"$(wc -l <data)" -n 10000 >line_numbers
```

The testing environment was a laptop with a i7-2670QM Intel quad-core processor, 16 GiB of memory, SSD storage, GNU/Linux, `bash` 5.0 and GNU tools.
The only dimension I measured has been the execution time, by means of the `time` shell builtin.

Here I'm considering:

- The `sed` solution from [Weijun Zhou's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/506236/315749).
- The `awk` solution from [Micha's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/506381/315749).
- The `perl` solution from [wurtel's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/506226/315749).
- The `join` solution above.

`perl` seems to be the fastest:

```bsh
$ time perl_script line_numbers data | wc -l
10000

real    14m51.597s
user    14m41.878s
sys     0m9.299s
```

`awk`'s performance looks comparable:

```bsh
$ time awk 'FNR==NR { seen[$0]++ }; FNR!=NR && FNR in seen' line_numbers data | wc -l
10000

real    29m3.808s
user    28m52.616s
sys     0m10.709s
```

`join`, too, appears to be comparable:

```bsh
$ time join <(sort padded_line_numbers) <(nl -w 12 -n rz data) | wc -l
10000

real    28m24.053s
user    27m52.857s
sys     0m28.958s
```

Note that the sorted version mentioned above has roughly no performance penalty over this one.

Finally, `sed` appears to be significantly slower: I killed it after approximately nine hours:

```bsh
$ time sed -nf <(sed 's/$/p/' line_numbers) data | wc -l
^C

real    551m12.747s
user    550m53.390s
sys     0m15.624s
```

Comment: I suspect there are too many no-ops in the `sed` solution.

Comment: @WeijunZhou As you noted in your answer, yes, `sed`'s performance is in line with that of the alternatives (or better) for small ranges of lines.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a perl script for this. I came up with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# usage: thisscript linenumberslist.txt contentsfile

unless (open(IN, $ARGV[0])) {
        die "Can't open list of line numbers file '$ARGV[0]'\n";
}
my %linenumbers = ();
while (<IN>) {
        chomp;
        $linenumbers{$_} = 1;
}

unless (open(IN, $ARGV[1])) {
        die "Can't open contents file '$ARGV[1]'\n";
}
$. = 0;
while (<IN>) {
        print if defined $linenumbers{$.};
}

exit;
```

This first reads the list of line numbers that we're interested in into an associative array, where the line numbers are the key. `chomp` removes the newline at the end of the line, `$_` is the line itself.

Next the data file is opened, and when the line number is an existing key in the array of line numbers, then the line is printed.

The `$.` is perl's line number counter, this increments for every line read. As this is counted across files, I reset it to zero before reading any lines of the data file.

This could probably be written much more in "perl" style, but I prefer to keep it a bit more readable.

If the list of lines you want to extract is very large, this may not be the most efficient way, but I find that perl is often amazingly efficient at these things.

If you require the lines to be extracted in the order that they are listed, i.e. not sequentially, then it becomes a lot more complicated...

Answer (score 3):

One liner, using `sed`:

```
sed -nf <(sed 's/$/p/' linenumberfile) contentfile
```

To keep the original order in `linenumberfile`, you can do

```
sed -nf <(sed 's/$/p/' linenumberfile) contentfile | paste <(nl linenumberfile | sort -n -k 2,2) - | sort -n -k 1,1 | cut -f 3-
```

**Explanation**:

```
sed 's/$/p/' linenumberfile
```

generates a `sed` script which prints the specified line. The script is then fed into another `sed` (with `-n` to suppress default printing of the pattern space) to do the actual printing. Since `sed` process the content file line by line, the output will be in the same order as in the content file. Note that this is a **one-pass process** so I would expect the speed to be acceptable.

To accelerate the process, one can change `p` to `{p;b}` and add a `q` at the end of the generated `sed` script.

To retain the order of the lines as they are in the line number file, `nl` is used to add "line numbers" to the line number file. So a line number file

```
4
5
2
```

would become

```
1 4
2 5
3 2
```

The first column records the original order in the line number file.

The file with "line numbers" is then `sort`ed and `paste`d to the output of `sed`, to make

```
3 2    content_of_line2
1 4    content_of_line4
2 5    content_of_line5
```

then it is `sort`ed using the 1st column as the key, to finally obtain

```
1 4    content_of_line4
2 5    content_of_line5
3 2    content_of_line2
```

Finally, `cut` is used to remove the 2 extra columns.

**Benchmarking**

It seems `sed` would do best for a few lines, but `perl` is the way to go for 10000 lines as specified in the question.

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -A 4 -m 1 processor
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 60
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4590 CPU @ 3.30GHz

$ wc -l linenumber
10 linenumber

$ wc -l content
8982457 content

$ file content
content: ASCII text

$ time bash -c "sed -nf <(sed 's/$/p/' linenumber) content > /dev/null"    
real    0m0.791s
user    0m0.661s
sys     0m0.133s

$ time bash -c "awk 'FNR==NR { seen[$0]++ }; FNR!=NR && FNR in seen' linenumber content > /dev/null"
real    0m3.061s
user    0m2.908s
sys     0m0.152s

$ time bash -c "./ln.pl linenumber content > /dev/null"
real    0m1.706s
user    0m1.582s
sys     0m0.124s

$ ./genlinenumber.py 100 > linenumber
$ wc -l linenumber
100 linenumber

$ time bash -c "sed -nf <(sed 's/$/p/' linenumber) content > /dev/null"
real    0m3.326s
user    0m3.164s
sys     0m0.164s

$ time bash -c "awk 'FNR==NR { seen[$0]++ }; FNR!=NR && FNR in seen' linenumber content > /dev/null"
real    0m3.055s
user    0m2.890s
sys     0m0.164s

$ time bash -c "./ln.pl linenumber content > /dev/null"
real    0m1.769s
user    0m1.604s
sys     0m0.165s
```

If it is required to retain the order of lines, the command after the first `|` can still be used since the time is negligible.

```
$ ./genlinenumber.py 10000 > linenumber
$ wc -l linenumber
10000 linenumber

$ time bash -c "./ln.pl linenumber content > extract"
real    0m1.933s
user    0m1.791s
sys     0m0.141s

$ time bash -c "paste <(nl linenumber | sort -n -k 2,2) extract | sort -n -k 1,1 | cut -f 3- > /dev/null"
real    0m0.018s
user    0m0.012s
sys     0m0.005s
```

Comment: Done. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Do common versions of `sed` support line numbers larger than 32 bits?

Comment: You are right. I made a mistake in last edits.

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

```
micha@linux-micha: /tmp
$ cat numbers.txt
1
2
4
5

micha@linux-micha: /tmp
$ cat sentences.txt
alpha
bravo
charlie
delta
echo
foxtrott

micha@linux-micha: /tmp
$ awk 'FNR==NR { seen[$0]++ }; FNR!=NR && FNR in seen' numbers.txt sentences.txt
alpha
bravo
delta
echo
```

Comment: This one invokes `awk` many times and will be really slow if `sentences.txt` is a huge file.

Comment: W. Zhou is right. Thank you! So I'll think twice.

Comment: So, edited my 1st awk approach. Now awk is invoked 1x. May be this is fast enough?